# how do I extract all pixel values from a certain ROI and then store it as a CSV file and again use that csv file to get back that ROI

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, face-detection, dlib

[After applying mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSxeH.jpg) [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZbmg.jpg)

```
import cv2
import dlib
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("Aayush.jpg")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
msk = np.zeros_like(img_gray)
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
faces = detector(img_gray)
for face in faces:
  landmarks = predictor(img_gray, face)
  lp = []
  for n in range(0,68):
    x = landmarks.part(n).x
    y = landmarks.part(n).y
    lp.append((x,y))
    p = np.array(lp, np.int32)
    #cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
convexhull = cv2.convexHull(p)
#cv2.polylines(img, [convexhull], True, (255,0,0), 3)
cv2.fillConvexPoly(msk, convexhull, 255)
img1 = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = msk)
```

img1 containsa complete black image with face cut from img, I just require the pixel values of face portion and not complete image

Comment: Asking a question about image processing without providing an image is not a recipe for success....

Comment: Mark Setchell I have added the images. thank you for guiding

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Expected output is a csv file containing the pixel values of only the face portion. which I can later convert back in image.

Answer (score 1):

As original image and mask have not been provided in the question itself. I am assuming a simple input image and a mask image with circular cavity as:

[image: mask image] [image]

The mask here is a single channel matrix with a value of `255` in the central cavity. To get the pixel info inside the cavity only you can use following numpy operation:

```
pixel_info = original_image[mask == 255]
# You may need to convert the numpy array to Python list.
pixel_info_list = pixel_info.tolist()
```

Now you may serialize the `list` to any format you want ([csv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) in this case.)

Full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

original_image = cv2.imread("/path/to/lena.png")
mask = np.zeros(original_image.shape[:2], dtype=original_image.dtype)

mask = cv2.circle(mask, (256, 256), 100, [255], -1)

pixel_info = original_image[mask == 255]
pixel_info_list = pixel_info.tolist()
```

Comment: I have added the original image and the other processed image(img1 as described in question) can you please check the images and tell me!! Thank you

Comment: This answer didn't solved your problem? What is the issue now ?

Comment: After storing this list to a csv.. can I convert it back to Image?